# Why would Recovery show in Volumes if I've not booted into recovery mode?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, recovery

This is a screenshot of /Volumes on a 2020 MacBook Pro with Catalina 10.15.7:
[image]

Why would Recovery show as a local volume if I've not booted into Recovery Mode recently?

It appeared to mount itself for some reason.

I don't have FileVault enabled, so that can't be the cause.

diskutil Recovery output from Terminal:

```
johndoe@MacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil info Recovery
   Device Identifier:         disk1s4
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1s4
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk1

   Volume Name:               Recovery
   Mounted:                   No

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Booter Disk:               disk1s3
   Recovery Disk:             disk1s4
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Volume UUID:               93EC3582-6942-41C5-B59F-61EFA4BD1940
   Disk / Partition UUID:     93EC3582-6942-41C5-B59F-61EFA4BD1940

   Disk Size:                 500.0 GB (499963174912 Bytes) (exactly 976490576 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Container Total Space:     500.0 GB (499963174912 Bytes) (exactly 976490576 512-Byte-Units)
   Container Free Space:      458.4 GB (458390020096 Bytes) (exactly 895293008 512-Byte-Units)

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

   This disk is an APFS Volume.  APFS Information:
   APFS Container:            disk1
   APFS Physical Store:       disk0s2
   Fusion Drive:              No
   FileVault:                 No
   Locked:                    No
```

diskutil list info from Terminal:

```
johndoe@MacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.3 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     28.5 GB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 80.1 MB    disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s5
```

Username changed for privacy.

Is this something I need to worry about?

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from `diskutil info Recovery` and `diskutil list`.

Comment: Output added, fixed. Should add it has been unmounted, two reboots since posting this.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in the output you posted. The output does show the `Recovery` volume as unmounted while your image shows the volume as mounted. I assume you unmounted the volume before executing the commands.

Comment: I've seen this a couple of times with Catalina: the Recovery partition would show up. A reboot fixed it. I haven't seen this behavior anymore since upgrading to Big Sur.